# How to specify name and componetes in <script setup> scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I would like to know how can i define `name`and `components` in a  `<script setup>` mode.
in a `none <script setup` mode, i can do the following:

```
export default {
name: 'App',
props: ['foo','greetingMessage'],
components: {
    HelloWorld
},
```

how can i achieve the same thing in `<script setup>` mode please

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  <span>greetingMessage:{{ greetingMessage }}</span>
</template>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import {defineProps} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['foo','greetingMessage'])

name: 'App'
components: {
  HelloWorld
}

console.log("props:",props)
console.log("props.foo:",props.foo)
console.log("props.greetingMessage:",props.greetingMessage)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add one more **script** tag and specify component's name there.

**Just like this:**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponentName",
};
</script>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import {defineProps} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['foo','greetingMessage'])

name: 'App'
components: {
  HelloWorld
}

console.log("props:",props)
console.log("props.foo:",props.foo)
console.log("props.greetingMessage:",props.greetingMessage)

</script>
```